# stringBuilder throwing invalid arguments

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

can anyone tell me why `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType, key, script.ToString, true);` is returning the best overload method for...has invalid arguments...I believe the script is the issue

```
 StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
            string key = "setTableName";
            if (Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Page.GetType(), key) == false)
            {
                script.Append("\ng_tableName ='");
                script.Append(tableName + "';");

                script.Append("\ng_layerName ='");
                script.Append(layerName + "';");
            }
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType, key, script.ToString, true);
```

Comment: You're passing `ToString` instead of calling it. Therefore, you end up passing a function instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

As **Frédéric Hamidi** said just replace `script.ToString` with `script.ToString()` to call a function instead of passing it as an argument :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), key, script.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. and well spotted but I also had to change this.Page to Page & this.GetType to Page.GetType